# Работа с двумерным массивом символов

Tags: java, массивы, java-8

Нужна помощь с заданием, есть массив:

```
char[][] tab = {
    {'S', 'a', 'm', 's', 'u', 'n', 'g'},
    {'N', 'o', 'k', 'i', 'a'},
    {'A', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e'},
    {'B', 'l', 'a', 'c', 'k', 'B', 'e', 'r', 'r', 'y'},
    {'A', 'l', 'c', 'a', 't', 'e', 'l'},
    {'S', 'o', 'n', 'y'},
    {'J', 'o', 'l', 'l', 'a'},
};
```

Нужно проверить, повторяются ли в каждом отдельном названии хотя бы 2 буквы (вне зависимости от их регистра).
Я написал такой цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < tab[i].length - 1; j++){
        if (tab[i][j] == tab[i][j+1]){
            System.out.println(tab[i][j] + " из " + i + " названия повторяются.");
        }
    }
}
```

Как результат получил:

- `p` из 2 названия повторяются.
- `r` из 3 названия повторяются.
- `l` из 6 названия повторяются.

Как мне изменить мой код, чтобы учитывались буквы верхнего регистра?

Comment: Только что заметил что мой цикл даёт не правильный вывод даже не учитывая большие буквы

Comment: он выводит индексы не позиции, просто прибавляйте 1 к индексам

Comment: он отсчитывает позиции в массиве с нуля

Comment: что касается больших букв, можно сделать все буквы маленькие

Comment: посмотрите в таблице ascii, где большик буквы и маленькие буквы. затем char можно кастануть в int, получив место в таблице ascii прибавить или вычесть что то и обратно кастануть в char, будет другая буква

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перевести все в один регистр, а потом сравнивать.

Или банально

```java
if (Character.toLowerCase(tab[i][j]) == Character.toLowerCase(tab[i][j+1])){
```

или с извращениями

```java
for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++){
  if (tab[i].length >= 2) {
    char prev = Character.toLowerCase(tab[i][0]);
    for (int j = 1; j < tab[i].length; j++){
      char cur = Character.toLowerCase(tab[i][j]);
      if (prev == cur){
        System.out.println(cur + " из " + i + " названия повторяются.");
      }
      prev = cur;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Буквы к нижнему регистру нужно привести `Character::toLowerCase`:

```java
char[] tab1 = {'S', 'a', 'm', 's', 'u', 'n', 'g'};

IntStream.range(0, tab1.length)
        // обходим коды символов
        .map(i -> tab1[i])
        // приводим к нижнему регистру
        .mapToObj(Character::toLowerCase)
        // считаем колличество, собираем в карту
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                e -> (char) e.intValue(),
                Collectors.counting()))
        // обходим карту
        .entrySet().stream()
        // сортируем по количеству в обратном порядке
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
        // отбираем повторяющиеся буквы
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
        // выводим результат
        .forEach(e ->
                System.out.println(e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue())); // s=2
```